# Runtime.ImportModuleError while executing AWS lambda typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, runtime, importerror

I am using `aws-cdk` to create the lambda function so for that I have created one folder at root name as `lambda`, inside that I have three folders `functions`, `handlers` and `utils`.

My folder structure is as below

```
-- lambda
   -- handlers
      -- createUserHandler.ts
   -- functions
      -- createUser.ts
   -- utils
-- sqs
```

The folder `handlers` will have the handle function which will be the starting point of execution of lambda during invocation and folder `functions` have some business logic to perform some operations. I am calling one method which is written in the `createUser.ts` file from `createUserHandler.ts`. I am getting below error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "createUser"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 23,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "Error: Cannot find module '../functions/createUser'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/createUserHandler.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

AWS cdk code of lambda creation

```
const createPayment = new lambda.Function(this, 'CreatePayment', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      handler: 'createUserHandler.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("src/lambda/handlers"),
      timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(5),
      functionName: `createUser-${stage}`,
      memorySize: 1024,
      role: lambdaExecutionRole,
    });
```

createUserHandler.ts

```
import createUser = require("../functions/createUser");

export async function handler(event:Event) {
    return await createPayment.default(event.arguments.user);
}
```

createUser.ts

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function createUser(user) {
    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.USER_TABLE,
        Item: user
    }
    try {
        await docClient.put(params).promise();
        return user;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('DynamoDB error: ', err);
        return null;
    }
}

export default createUser;
```

I am completely new to typescript and struggling for the last 24 hours please help me to get it resolved.
Thanks